# Having an "edit" controller to deal with user editing? Does this design make sense?

Tags: php, codeigniter, controller, editing, verification

Here is the flow:

1. User creates a text based post.
2. User edits a text based post (an edit page with the post info is displayed)
3. User submits the changes to the post (a request sent to the post controller)

Now, if I have MULTIPLE types of posts, I have to check in steps 2 and 3 that the user is indeed updating the RIGHT type of post because someone could very well alter the URL to edit a post of type A when it's really of type B. This leads to a lot of redundant code, such as ...

```
if(user is indeed the editor && the post type is correct) show the edit page
```

I think it would make a lot of sense to have an EDIT controller that does all the verification needed in the constructor (or maybe a base class?), and then calls the method. Have you encountered similar issues like this - and if not, does this make any design sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[CodeIgniter is an MVC](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/overview/mvc.html). That means that your controllers serve as an intermediate between your models (your data), and your view (front-end). "Edit" is an action that you do to objects, like data. Data objects should be organized within a controller, which calls the actual edit functions from the model.

I'm assuming you have a Post controller. At its core, it should have basic CRUD functions, like adding and editing posts. It should look something like this:

```
class Post extends CI_Controller
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function index()
    {
        // List all posts, perhaps?
    }

    function add()
    {
        // Add a post
    }

    function edit($post_id)
    {
        // Edit a post
    }

    function view($post_id)
    {
        // View a post
    }

}
```

That will give you the following pages:

- http://example.com/post
- http://example.com/post/add
- http://example.com/post/view/1
- http://example.com/post/edit/1

Checking for user permissions is its own chapter. If you are using a library like [Tank Auth](http://www.konyukhov.com/soft/tank_auth/), you can check permissions like so:

```
if ($this->tank_auth->is_logged_in()) {
    // Do stuff
}
```

That should go at the beginning of each function - or in the `__construct()`, if you want to DRY it up completely.

Good luck.